# Good ways to release build instructions?

Tags: build-process

For open source projects, it's sometimes difficult to find clear build instructions. As a user, I sometimes have to figure out a build process for a piece of software, but then have no obvious way to make that information widely available. What are good ways to release that information?

Someone please make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first place I tend to look is in a readme file at the root of the source tree.

Another option, of course, is, if there's a documentation page for the project (and shouldn't there be?) you could have a document there that is specifically about building.

Comment: I meant as user. I would appreciate it if more projects had a wiki where users could add information including build information.

Comment: The whole point of open source is that anyone can be part of the project.  Join up, and submit a commit to add your instructions.  All open source projects need and are very happy to have documentation committers, not just developers.